# Does it cost to retrieve the currently logged in user in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I know how to handle logIns and signUps and how to get current User but I was wondering if it costs a read if we get the user that is logged In or otherwise getting null if not logged in. 
In otherwords does
                firebase.auth().currentUser;
also takes up a read request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebase Authentication APIs don't cost anything (other than phone authentication, which is covered in the pricing page).

When you say "read request", it sounds like you're talking about Firestore, which is a completely different product with different billing.  Calling Firebase Auth APIs has no impact on Firestore billing.  Firestore is billed based on your usage of its own APIs.  Anything under `firebase.auth()` is not at all part of that.